# Category tree structure with node count using JPA

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, self-join

I have a category tree structure, using JPA with eclipse link.
Each category in the tree includes items, and I want to select all categories along with their items count.

The code I inherited used to calculate the number of items offline, and update the category, and use the cool JPA trick for selecting the categories like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "topLevel", query = "SELECT categories.* FROM categories WHERE categories.parent_id IS NULL")
public class Category {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer item_count;
    private Long parent_id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private List<Categories> categories;
}
```

When running the native query - I get all the categories populated in the tree structure.

However, now I have a new filter that doesn't allow the user to see all the items in the category. So I can no longer calculate the items offline.
I tried to use a join so I can calculate it online, like this:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "topLevel", query = "SELECT categories.*, count(*) as item_count FROM categories, items_to_categories WHERE categories.id = items_to_categories.category_id and some_user_specific_query and categories.parent_id IS NULL GROUP BY categories.id")
```

but this doesn't populate the lower levels with the right items count.

Since I am using Eclipse Link, I can't use a formula field that is not supported in this JPA implementation.

Any ideas on how to change my model in order to get it to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want an Item count you can either query for it, such as using JPQL.  This will return an Object[] including the Category and its Integer item count.  If you want to use a native SQL query, then you will need to use a SqlResultSetMapping.

If you want the item count in Category, then you could define a database VIEW that makes this appear as a column and map to the view.

Another option is to map the items of the Category, then to get the item count, just access the size() of the items in Java (you could use join or batch fetching to load the items efficiently).

Comment: Is it possible without any additional queries? This is what I am doing now, but it's not elegant, and increases latency. The other option is not good since it's a tree, and the count will return only the current level, or the subcategories count without further descending to lower levels.

Comment: The other option is to update the itemCount every time an Item is added to the Tree or any of its children.  You could do this in your addItem() method.